Area of a trapezoid
A trapezoid is divided into four triangles by its two diagonals.
The two triangles bordering the two parallel sides of the trapezium,
have the area A and D.
What is the area of ​​the entire trapezoid in terms of A and D?


Mark the other areas as $B$ and $C$ and the lengths of the line segments joining each corner to the diagonal intersections $p, q, r$ and $s$ as follows

 

Then we have the following

 As triangles with area $A$ and $C$ have the same height from the bases formed by the lengths $p$ and $s$ it follows that $\frac{A}{p} = \frac{C}{s}$ or, equivalently $\frac{A}{C} = \frac{p}{s}$.
 Similarly, $\frac{B}{D} = \frac{p}{s}$.
 Combining these we have $$AD = BC$$

Secondly,

 As the triangles formed by areas $B$ and $D$ has the same height and base as the triangle formed by the areas $C$ and $D$, it follows that $B+D = C+D$ or $$B=C$$ Hence, $$B=C=\sqrt{AD}$$

This gives the total area of the trapezoid as

 $$A+B+C+D = A+D+2\sqrt{AD} = \left(\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{D} \right)^2$$


@ACB agreed....
